# Maven - Inherit parent pom's modules

Tags: maven, multiple-inheritance

First, I'll explain what I'm trying to do, since this may or may not make sense.

I have a few different applications which start up embedded servlet containers to run integration tests when they build.

In the future, I would like to separate these plugin configurations into their own poms.  I have reasons for doing this because other projects would need to start up a tomcat while deploying another project to it, to test its code.  Also, the configurations can be quite lengthy as each project would need separate context files for datasource configs etc.

For example, I'd have a web client project.  The web client project would use configuration to deploy and run the server's webapp in an embedded jetty/tomcat when the build is invoked with a certain profile.

This is simple enough to do with one large parent pom, or parent poms inheriting other parent poms.

child-project.pom -> ci-parent -> app1-it-deploy-config.pom -> app2-it-deploy-config.pom -> app3-it-deploy-config.pom

That just doesn't look right to me.  I was wondering if it was possible (I don't think it is, because I tried a couple different ways) to have a parent pom with module poms.

If a child project inherits from the parent pom, it gets extra configuration (separated out by profiles) from all of the parent's submodules.

So, what I'm trying to do

- ci-parent

  - app1-it-deploy-config
  - app2-it-deploy-config
  - app3-it-deploy-config

If a child project (other than app(1-3)-it-deploy-config) inherits ci-parent, configuration in app(1-3)-it-deploy-config will become available to the child project

I have a solution either way, but from an organization standpoint, I don't necessarily agree with a long chain of inheritance.

Have any of you guys dealt with this before?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not following exactly.  Modules do not have to have the packaging pom as a parent.  The two are managed separately.  For example if you have web projects and non web projects you might have different parents for either set, but you might have the same packaging pom to build it all.  Could you show some example code you have and specifically the behavior you want to avoid?